# Build RPM from DRPM on Fedora Linux

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, rpm, repository

I am creating a private Fedora Linux mirror (os & updates repositories of RPMS and DRPMS). Of course, I'm doing that using rsync and everything is working well... except that I'm using a very slow 256kbit/s connection and downloads take ages.

As the updates repository contains both RPMS and DRPMS, I was wondering whether it is possible to:

(1) only rsync the DRPMS
(2) build the RPMS locally

Anyone has done something similar?

Thanks beforehand.

[edit]

I've found [a page explaining how to create DRPMs as well as build RPMs from DRPMs](http://cholla.mmto.org/computers/linux/rpm/drpm.html). I'm investigating if this can be used.

Anyone has a document from Fedora which explains their policy concerning DRPMs e.g. from what RPMs are DRPMs created? Is it the original version found on the DVD or the previous version found in the updates repository?

Answer (score 1):

As for 1: No, downloading only DRPMs will sure not be enough. You will need at least one RPM per package and use this with DRPMs to build further RPMs.

As for 2: sure it is - that's exactly what yum does. (Now just to figure out how...)

Try asking on #yum IRC channel on freenode.

Comment: It seems yum builds the latest RPM from the DRPM and the package already installed on the system. I assume that this already installed package is the previous latest version. So, theoretically speaking, it should be possible to rebuild the latest RPMs from the previous RPMs and the latest DRPMs. Let me try.